# What happens when two processes listen on the same Berkeley/Unix [file] socket?

Tags: c, socket, unix-sockets

What happens when I set up two processes to listen to the same [Berkeley socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)?

Do messages get routed to both? Neither? One of the two? If so, how?

Concretely, I can start two `gunicorn` processes with the same path for `--bind unix:` and no obvious error occurs:

```bsh
gunicorn --bind=unix:/path/to/some/socket
```

This seems like a very simple question, although I have not been able to find a clear-cut answer on SE or elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two processes **cannot** bind (and listen) to the same unix socket. A process which tries to bind to an already existing unix socket will get an `EADDRINUSE` error.

> Concretely, I can start two gunicorn processes with the same --bind unix:/ and no obvious error occurs

It's probable that your `gunicorn` process is actually removing the socket file before binding to it, and so it ends up binding to a *different* unix socket.

Keep in mind that the actual address of a unix socket is the `device_id:inode` tuple, not the path through which it was accessed. If you remove a unix socket, a program which binds to the same path will end up creating a different socket file, with a different inode.

Note: all this applies to "normal", filesystem-resident Unix sockets. Linux also has *abstract* unix sockets, where the name of the socket is its actual address, and which do not use any kind of filesystem object. For these too, you won't be able to bind two sockets to the same address.

Comment: For IP sockets you can have two processes bind, there is a flag for it. And in ether case you could fork after bind. In the case of IP sockets, I have read that the kernel will load balance the work load (this may be simple alternation). My guess is that other socket types are the same.

Comment: Your guess is wrong.

Comment: so what happens after a `fork`? Is it one of those un-defined behaviour things?

Comment: fork() has nothing to do with it. If two processes inherit the same *unbound* socket, only one of them could bind it.

Comment: I mean `fork` after the bind.

Comment: Then both processes could use the *same* socket, just like two threads of a multithreaded program do. Open files are not per-process objects; any file can be shared between multiple processes. Don't mix that up with `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT` which do not work on Unix sockets.

Comment: Good lead re: the actual socket address being `device_id:inode`. Perhaps this hypothesis about `guniocrn` removing the socket file and creating a new one could be tested by seeing if `/path/to/some/socket` is a different `inode` after starting the second `guniocrn` process?

Comment: @ijoseph if you're on Linux, you can easily check with `strace -fe trace=unlink gunicorn ...`. Most programs which listen on a Unix socket remove it before binding to it; there's no other robust way to do it.

Comment: Ah, googling that last sentence brought me [here (link)](https://gavv.github.io/articles/unix-socket-reuse/) which has great info on the matter. "The problem is that if we run two instances of our process, the second one will silently remove socket used by the first one, instead of reporting a failure."